# How to send toolbar message from c++?

Tags: visual-c++

I am creating a Internet Explorer 6 plugin using VC++. I would like to know, how can I send messages like TBN_TOOLBARCHANGE from my C++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use SendMessage API. For this, you need to know the target handle of window to cause the desired effect. You may use FindWindow() to match a window against certain characteristics, and Spy++ would help you see what others are doing.